# SQLite query hangs in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a local SQLite database with 5 tables, and I have a background thread that's loading data into them.  The first 4 work fine, so I'm not completely without a clue. The following method is in a class derived from an abstract parent class that owns the SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public POJO getPOJO(String num) {
    String where = POJO_NUMBER + " = ? ";
    Log.v(TAG, where);
    String[] whereArgs = { num };
    this.openReadableDB();
    Log.v(TAG, "db args=" + num);

// and here's the problem child:
    Cursor cursor = db.query(POJO_TABLE, null, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);

    Log.v(TAG, cursor.toString());
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    POJO p = getPojoFromCursor(cursor); // this just copies the cursor fields into the POJO object
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    this.closeDB();
    return p;
}
```

db is defined in the base class as

```
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
```

On the first of these objects that I try to process, execution goes into db.query and never comes back.  Eventually I usually get an assertion that the db wasn't closed, though that seems to be a downstream effect, rather than a clue.

I tried bumping the database version number, so that the existing files would get thrown away and recreated - that made no difference.

Although I've been doing mobile development for a while this is the first time I've had to use a local SQLite database, so I'd appreciate any suggestions on where to look next.  TIA.

EDIT 5/1 7a pdt:
The size of the table is small - less than 100 rows.

here is the creation sql:

```
public static final String CREATE_POJO_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + POJO_TABLE + " (" +
        POJO_ID     + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        POJO_NUMBER + " TEXT," +
        POJO_FIRST  + " TEXT," +
        POJO_LAST   + " TEXT, " +
        POJO_ATTR1  + " INTEGER," +
        POJO_ATTR2  + " INTEGER," +
        POJO_ATTR3  + " INTEGER" +

        ");";
```

It's cleaned up some since last night - I had a comma after the INTEGER for ATTR3

```
        POJO_ATTR3  + " INTEGER," +
```

which I removed then later found out shouldn't matter.

Comment: How large is that table?

Comment: Can you add the table creation code to your question, please?

Comment: Query is starting to look like a red herring.  Since I'm loading data where the source db queries use callbacks to report success or failure, and then digging deeper into the data tree on each success call, I wonder if I've stumbled on some sort of thread limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is why I love and hate programming.  I have bent the program to my will (Yea!) but have lost a day in the process (Boo!).

The code snippet above is essentially the same for all 5 of the classes being stored in the database - it turned out that this one wasn't the culprit, it was the one just upstream.

THAT unfortunate entity needed to get a piece of info from another class, and so called this method:

```
public int getMinimum() {return minimum;}
```

seems simple, right?  well, in the information-source class, guess how minimum is defined?

```
 private Integer minimum;
```

and guess what happens when minimum is null?  bad things, man, bad things.

a simple change:

```
public int getMinimum() { return (minimum == null ? 0 : minimum); }
```

and now all is right with the world.

Except for the day that I lost beating my brain against this particular brick wall.

Just in case someone else stumbles across this with their own personal buried wackiness:  DDMS is your friend.  I'd never used it before, but have become quite the fan of being able to examine the database, and watch what's going on.  Even if it is primarily useful with the emulator which is still dog slow compared to a device.

Log is also your friend.  Use him liberally.  I thought I had a structural problem (the aforementioned thread limitation), when if I'd buckled down at the beginning and just thrown a log after every statement (which is where I ended up anyways since refactoring the code did nothing to solve the problem) - I might have six of those hours back.

What a day.